# Retrieving multiple linked lists in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, linked-list

I have a database, which is basically a collection of multiple linked-lists. There are columns `id`, `next_id`, and a lot more other columns describing the rows, but these two are important for the question. They are in a normal single-linked-list fashion, so `next_id` can be `NULL` to indicate the end of the chain, however, the whole table has multiple of these linked lists (~12M). To illustrate, here are couple example rows

```
id | next_id
1 | 3
2 | 5
3 | NULL
4 | NULL
5 | 4
```

What I would need, is to create a new table, where for each original id, there are multiple rows of all possible ids, that follow in the linked list. Example for such table, created from the example table above would be

```
id | next_id
1 | 3
2 | 4
2 | 5
5 | 4
```

**Is there a way, how to retrieve such a followup table easily?** What I'm doing right now are recursive joins. Most of these chains are rather short (around ~5 entries), however, some of them get very ugly (around those ~1K long chains), so with recursive joins it just isn't really feasible (that is ~1k joins, or ~10 recursive joins, if doing in a binary fashion, which start to fail in Hive). The whole original table has around 50M of the rows

Btw, we are talking about Hive, but I don't think it should affect the idea much, and I cannot alter the structure of the original table to add more columns there.

Thanks

Comment: Many databases support the standard functionality of recursive CTEs.  Hive does not.  You need to do looping at the application level in Hive.  Or, alternatively, store the data with a "path" from to each node.

Comment: I can also access the same data using PySpark. Would you know if that would help the problem?

Comment: PySpark also doesn't support recursive subqueries but it might be a better environment for writing a loop.